# In OS X, why does one external HD mount as fusefs and another as ntfs?

Tags: macos, ntfs, ntfs-3g, macfuse

I'm on a Mac running Snow Leopard with the old/free version of MacFUSE and NTFS-3G.  I have one external harddrive that was pre-formatted in NTFS and mounts itself with fusefs, so everything's great.  I just added a 2nd hard drive that I repartitioned and formatted in Windows XP with ntfs, which my mac mounts using a read-only ntfs driver.

Why are the drives being mounted differently, and how can I get the new one to use ntfs-3g?

Thanks!

(Here's the output from a mount command, if it's relevant)

```
/dev/disk2s1 on /Volumes/OldDrive (fusefs, local, nodev, nosuid, synchronous)
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/NewDrive (ntfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)
```

Comment: Figured it out, actually:
Short answer: running a simple chkdsk /f in Windows on the incorrectly-working drive fixed a number of errors and allowed the drive be mounted correctly in OS X.

Longer answer: manually calling ntfs-3g on the drive (i.e. sudo ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/MountPoint) gave a better error message.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?  You can then (after a brief wait) "accept" it as correct.  It would help future answer-seekers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: running a simple `chkdsk /f` in Windows on the incorrectly-working drive fixed a number of errors and allowed the drive to work correctly again.

Longer answer: Manually calling `ntfs-3g` on the drive (i.e. `sudo ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/MountPoint`) gave me a much better error message--one that told me to run `chkdsk` in Windows!